# Removing Server tag in Header of IIS10

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I am asking this question here because every other trick in the book from various sites including microsofts has failed to fix this for me.

I have added

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
```

in **<system.webserver>**

Then i also added

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false"/>
  </system.web>
```

also added

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
       <clear />
      </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

However none of this seems to remove the "Server" header from the response.

Any idea as to what else i can try other than URlRewrite or outboundrule??

Comment: i tried to resolve [the same issue](https://serverfault.com/q/941585/321311) few years back to no avail. apparently, on some case the `Server` header is added by something on OS level outside of IIS control.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be You need more than just a single change.